# Could not set the list property. Invalid property array index - ComboBox issues

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, named-ranges

I know there are several questions with the same error code but none of the answers seemed transferable to my code.

I have a combobox on a userform in excel that I want to populate from a named range in my workbook. In

```
sub userform_initialize()    
Range("rngDept").Activate
Me.ComboBox1.List = Range("rngDept")
```

Where rngDept is the name of the range. The first line successfully selects the range I want but it will not load these values in to the combobox. I had this working last week but forgot ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False was set. I'm using the exact same approach so I don't know why it is now not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```Range("rngDept").value``` you also shouldn't need the ```.activate``` line.

Comment: I had already tried that, the code ran but the combobox on the form was empty which is why i put the activate line in to see if it was selecting the correct range, which it was.

Answer (score 0):

I scavenged this code from another site which has worked:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Populate Color combo box.
Dim rngColor As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")
For Each rngColor In ws.Range("ColorList")
Me.cboColor.AddItem rngColor.Value
Next rngColor
End Sub
```

Thanks.